# Create own state manager using Node JS events

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to build my own state manager using Node.js 'events' and modular ES6, but I'm a little bit confused on how to make it work. Basically I have a `Loader.js` which loads all the images I need. After it's finished loading I want to change the state in `Manager.js` to `Loaded` and for now just execute `console.log('Loaded all content!');`. I have the function to load my images, and I have the state manager, but how do I emit my event from `Loader.js` to let the StateManager run `changeState()`?

Edit: I tried this but it gives the error `Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined at Function.loadedImages`

**Loader.js**

```
'use strict';

import Manager from './Manager';

const DIRECTORY = 'assets/img/';

const IMG = {
  BACKGROUND_01: 'background_01.jpg',
  PLAYER_01: 'player_01.png',
  KEEPER_01: 'keeper_01.png'
}

export default class Loader {
  constructor() {
    this.load();
  }

  load() {
    this.imageCount = 0;
    this.loadCount = 0;

    this.loadImage(IMG.BACKGROUND_01);
    this.loadImage(IMG.PLAYER_01);
    this.loadImage(IMG.KEEPER_01);

    if (this.loadCount === this.imageCount) {
      console.log('Loaded images!');
      // Call Manager
      Manager.loadedImages();
    }
  }

  loadImage(image) {
    this.imageCount++;
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = DIRECTORY + image;
    img.onload = this.loadCount++;
    console.log('Loaded: ' + image);
  }
}
```

**Manager.js**

```
'use strict';

import emitter from 'events';
import Canvas from './Canvas';
import Loader from './Loader';

class StateManager extends emitter {
  constructor () {
    super();
  }
}

export default class Manager {
  constructor() {
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    this.Canvas = new Canvas();
    this.Loader = new Loader();

    this.state = new StateManager();
    this.state.on('loaded', this.changeState());
  }

  static loadedImages() {
    //Emit loaded event
    this.state.emit('loaded');
  }

  changeState() {
    //If state is loaded
    console.log('Loaded all content!');
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
Actually I fixed it, I had to pass the `stateManager` to `Loader`:

**Loader.js**

```
'use strict';

import Manager from './Manager';

const DIRECTORY = 'assets/img/';

const IMG = {
  BACKGROUND_01: 'background_01.jpg',
  PLAYER_01: 'player_01.png',
  KEEPER_01: 'keeper_01.png'
}

export default class Loader {
  constructor() {
  }

  setup(state) {
    this.state = state;
    this.load();
  }

  load() {
    this.imageCount = 0;
    this.loadCount = 0;

    this.loadImage(IMG.BACKGROUND_01);
    this.loadImage(IMG.PLAYER_01);
    this.loadImage(IMG.KEEPER_01);

    if (this.loadCount === this.imageCount) {
      console.log('Loaded images!');

      this.state.setState('loaded');
    }
  }

  loadImage(image) {
    this.imageCount++;
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = DIRECTORY + image;
    img.onload = this.loadCount++;
    console.log('Loaded: ' + image);
  }
}
```

Manager.js

```
'use strict';

import emitter from 'events';
import Canvas from './Canvas';
import Loader from './Loader';

class StateManager extends emitter {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.currentState = '';
  }

  setState(id) {
    this.currentState = id;
    console.log(this.currentState);

    this.emit(id);
  }
}

export default class Manager {
  constructor() {
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    this.state = new StateManager();
    this.state.on('loaded', this.changeState);

    this.Canvas = new Canvas();
    this.Loader = new Loader();

    this.Loader.setup(this.state);
  }

  changeState() {
    console.log('Loaded all content! Lets go!')
  }
}
```

Comment: `loadedImages` is `static` so you can't access the parameter `state`